# Can a person happen? Is "Zodanga happened" correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I was watching movie *John Carter* where there was some dialogue like this:

> — What happened here?
>       — Zodanga happened.

Here Zodanga was a bad guy in the movie.

I don't understand how **a guy** can **happen** at some place, like it was said in that conversation? We generally use *happened* like this:

> — What happened to you?
>       — Oh! I have been suffering from a head ache *or*
>       met an accident *or*
>       I haven't been sleeping lately,

but   we never say "Silvia happened to me" (as if Silvia was a bad person here).

Comment: To happen: (v. Int) to be, come, go, etc., casually or by chance: My friend happened along. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Happened

Comment: @Josh That's _a_ way the verb _happen_ can be used of people, but not the meaning in the asker’s context.

Comment: Yes, it is only related! And I put it as a note because it is an intransitive use of the verb 'to happen' that is worth a look.

Comment: "Silvia happened to me" is fine.

Comment: Quite simply, "XYZ Happened" is (now) a common form in English, particularly in the US.  An interesting question is, when did this arise?  I don't know.  The 1990s?

Comment: @JoeBlow, its useless comment, totally out of the discussion.

Comment: @paul I'm not sure it's useless.  The answer to a question like this might be "It's an accepted construction now, but it wouldn't have been 30 years ago."  Asking when or where it happened makes sense, since the site is about the English language and usage, and whether "X happened" is "legitimate" usage will vary depending on when and where it's used.

Comment: @Kris, but perhaps you are thinking of a different Silvia.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor the implicit question is "What does this mean?": "I don't understand how a guy can happen at some place". Answering that with "This is a common sentence" is not really helpful.

Comment: @AdrianoVaroliPiazza If the usage is not common everywhere, it's worthwhile to point out that "X is what people mean by this, but note that if you're outside of Y, people won't know what you mean."  Consider other regional variations like ["The car needs washed."](http://microsyntax.sites.yale.edu/needs-washed).  If paul was asking "can a car need washed?", it would make sense to explain that "in some places it can, but in most places, it can't.  Here's what it means in the places where it means something."

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Please tell me where do you read all that in Joe's comment. I only read "X happened is now a common form in English..."

Comment: @AdrianoVaroliPiazza "It's now common in English" isn't an sufficient answer.  Joe's comment, that paul called useless, pointed out that "An interesting question is, when did [this usage being common] arise?" The very title of the question is *Can a person happen? Is “Zodanga happened” correct?* If the usage isn't universal, a literal answer could be "it depends where you are."  The body of the question implicitly adds, "and what does it mean?"  A good answer will explain what it means (to address the body) and provide context about who uses it (to address the title question).

Comment: Related poem: “Do not fall in love with people like me. / 
I will take you to museums, and parks, and monuments, and kiss you in every beautiful place, so that you can never go back to them without tasting me like blood in your mouth. / 
I will destroy you in the most beautiful way possible. And when I leave you will finally understand, why storms are named after people.” 
― Caitlyn Siehl,

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Formally this can be analysed as an example of ***metonymy,*** a figure of speech in which a term that denotes one thing is used to refer to a related thing [[Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche)].

Here, the **name** Zodanga (which normally refers to a person) is used to refer to his **actions** (which are a related thing).

> — What happened here?
>   — Zodanga arrived and caused mayhem.

The “causing mayhem” is what happened; Zodanga is so closely related to that (as he was the cause) that his name is used to refer to the whole situation.

Similarly with *Silvia* in your example. It’s actually perfectly possible to use that construction if Silvia has a reputation for doing something particular. You refer to the person, and imply that what has happened is what they are famous for.

It is correct (as you note in the question) that it’s normally limited to bad events, and becomes slightly humorous when applied unexpectedly to someone’s **good** reputation:

> — What happened here?
>   — J. Paul Getty happened. That’s why they’re all waving $50 bills.

Even when used of bad events, this particular construction—using a person’s name metonymically with the verb *happen*—is rather informal and should be used mainly in informal contexts. Other types of metonymy naturally have their own level of formality, with some being very frequent in more formal or technical contexts; for example:

> HSBC dropped nearly ten points yesterday

– is something you’re quite likely to hear in a business meeting discussing stock prices. It is metonymy because *HSBC* here refers not to the bank or the corporation itself, but to the *price of HSBC shares*.

Comment: So, `metonymy` can't be used in a stake holder's meeting where in we just talk serious or where only Boss can make jokes.

Comment: @Paul Please read the Wikipedia article on metonymy linked to. Metonymy is just a type of figure of speech. If you're in a business meeting talking about stock prices and say, “HSBC dropped nearly ten points yesterday”, that's metonymy as well, because _HSBC_ is referring not to the bank or the corporation itself, but to _the price of HSBC shares_. This particular form of metonymy, though, using a person’s name to refer to their associated actions, is definitely informal and joking, and may not be appropriate in a business meeting.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, nice example...I understood now.

Comment: @Janus - actually the example you make with the HSBC stock price is quite common language  used in financial meetings. Only very formal meetings like AGM would use more formal language to refer to stock prices.

Comment: @Josh Yes, that's why I used that example.

Comment: @Janus Feel free to edit that into the answer. It deserves more permanence than a comment endows.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Done!

Comment: I think it's noteworthy that this form is most often used with names of *places*, (in)famous for one particular event: “… then Fukushima happened“, “… then Watergate happened”, “… then Woodstock happened”, etc.

Comment: @Emmet it's also probably important, for the benefit of non-native speakers of English, to point out that the examples you cite are fairly normal and could be found in almost any context, while "then Zodanga happened" is somewhat unusual, which gives it a certain (possibly humorous) emphasis.

Comment: Well Zodanga is a place name not a person name. So it's more a "Germany happened" rather than a "Hitler happened" but both work as answer to "what happened to Europe in 1939?"

Answer (score 10):

In addition to Andrew's very fine answer, I'd like to point out that '`Person's name` happened' can also signify the start of a relationship or meeting someone who made an impression.

> I was just living my life, and then, all of a sudden, Silvia happened.

Comment: ...and judging by the Silvias I know, boy do they happen ;)

Answer (score 9):

It's slightly humorous and playing on the ungrammatical-ness. Something like, "Zodanga is such a larger-than-life person, that when I say 'Zodanga happened,' you understand he is a force and know exactly what I mean." Perhaps most analogous to "a tornado happened," as a tornado is a noun whose mere presence indicates event-like qualities.

Answer (score 7):

I would also like to point out that Zodanga was, in fact, the name of a **city** in the story (*John Carter* is based on *A Princess of Mars* by Edgar Rice Burroughs).  This doesn't invalidate the accepted answer, except perhaps the example.

> — Zodanga happened.
>
> — Zodanga arrived and caused mayhem.
>
> — Zodanga's military arrived and caused mayhem.

The second version, which is given in the accepted answer, is actually still acceptable, as long as you realize that Zodanga is still a metonym for "Zodanga's military" or perhaps "Sab Than," the leader of Zodanga and the name of the primary antagonist of the movie.

An analogous situation is often heard in U.S. political news, where you might hear "the White House" in reference to the current President or his administration, "Capitol Hill" in reference to U.S. Congress, or even "Washington," which actually means Washington, D.C. and refers to the U.S. Government in general.

Comment: Considering in the _John Carter_ movie that Zodanga is a **mobile** city, it can certainly "arrive" somewhere. Potentially, it could even cause mayhem without involvement of the military (f.e. by running over something).

Answer (score 2):

BTW when non-native-english-speakers are asking about an idiom - we often forget to point out the obvious!

This figure of speech is a **humorous twist** on an earlier figure of speech ..

**"Shit happens."**

Fully explained here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shit_happens

Now, "shit happens" was a catchy phrase. People started changing it to a polite word, notably "magic happens" (I'd say that would have been a t-shirt design at first, maybe) and "kindness happens."

You then - I believe it followed in this order, but I'm not certain - people introduced this cool new use " happened", meaning, as Andrew explains, the characteristic actions (**usually mayhem**) that you associate with that fictional character (or real person) happened.

It would be fascinating to know the first use of this .. you can imagine it coming from, say, an action movie.

Indeed there are other variations as Bakabaka explains.  Another variation is with, oh, cultural phenomenon.  Oh, you might be explaining the transition in film from the new wave to pop effects movies, and you'd say something like "Everything was going along nicely with Goddard and Truffaut - and then Jaws happened."

Just as with the "Silvia" example, you tend to use it for "explosive, dramatic" things, I think.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that "Shit happens" is the origin of this phrase? It doesn't seem at all intuitive to me. This sounds more like folk etymology.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with "Shit happens."

Comment: Hi @chapka - I absolutely totally agree with you that I could be **completely wrong**. But it really sounds like that to me, and (not that it means anything) I just canvassed a couple others and they agreed.  So, I've asked a question on a site where someone might know! http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186991

Comment: If you are not sure and are guessing and have no proof, then your use of phrases like "[it] _is_ a humourous twist on..." is misleading.

Comment: I don't think it's *because of* _shit happens_, but I think the idea is similar.

Comment: +1 - even if it isn't wholly accurate, I believe the phrase had to contribute to the popularity of the `<proper noun> happened` idiom. Additionally, the linked wiki article traces the origin of the [minced oath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath) form to a radio show in **1941**. Media, especially broadcast, at that time was very conservative, meaning the origin of the phrase probably dates back at least a decade into the Great Depression. Anyways, I think the phrasing the asker is interested in severely post-dates the phrase Joe Blow proposes, certainly in terms of popularity.

Answer (score 2):

Remember the once-running Yahoo chat rooms? Now:

> A: What happened to Yahoo chat rooms?
>
> B:  Facebook happened!

The same story here.

Comment: If someone doesn't understand "Zodanga happened", why would they understand this?